# Grouping points into polygons ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, point, arctoolbox

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.1. I have a set of clustering points. I am trying to create a zone for these points. Is there a tool or script to group the points in an area and convert them to a polygon?

I don't have the POINT TO POLYGON tool available

Comment: Search here for convex hull.

Comment: If you have spatial analyst and want polygons to share edges, use euclidean allocation.

Comment: I think a picture showing what polygons you would be wanting to create for some sample points would be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the Minimum Bounding Geometry tool in the Features toolset, this will create polygons based on your point input with various possible geometry types